# In javascript, how do I test whether an object is a RowDataPacket object?

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

When querying mysql using node-mysql, I get results that look like this in the console:

```
console.log(result)
// RowDataPacket {user_id: 101, ActionsPerformed: 20}
```

I am wondering, is there a way to test whether or not an object is a RowDataPacket object?  Something like the following...

```
isRowDataPacket(result) // true
isRowDataPacket({user_id: 101, ActionsPerformed: 20}) // false
```

Comment: I think you are looking for the [`instanceof`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/instanceof) operator